# PGSQL user-defined function return type mismatch time zone conversion

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a user-defined function that takes a value of type "timestamp without time zone" and produces a value of the type "timestamp with time zone".  In my case, I want to convert it to Mountain Standard Time.

My function currently looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_mst(x timestamp without time zone) RETURNS 
timestamp with time zone 
AS $$ SELECT x AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'MST7MDT'; $$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
STRICT;
```

When I try to run this I get:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return timestamp with time zone
DETAIL:  Actual return type is timestamp without time zone.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "to_mst"
```

I know that `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'MST7MDT'` achieves the desired result.  I've used it many times.

I can't figure out what's going wrong.  Please help.

Comment: `select pg_typeof(current_timestamp::timestamp), pg_typeof(current_timestamp::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'MST7MDT');` `at time zone` changes `with time zone` to `without time zone` and vice versa. So using it twice does not changes the type of value. It is like minus sign: `-(-1)` gives you `1`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto you're right I needed to change the expected return type to `time stamp without time zone`.  That fixed it.